# How to get current timescale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game that speeds up time scale. I want to pause and resume it with the previous time scale.

```
private IEnumerator Speedup()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    Time.timeScale+=0.05f;
    StartCoroutine(Speedup());
}
public void pausegame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

public void unpausegame()
{
    Time.timeScale = ??;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable to store the previous scale during pause, and then reassign it in unpause.

```
private float _previousScale = 1;

private IEnumerator Speedup()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    Time.timeScale += 0.05f;
    StartCoroutine(Speedup());
}

public void pausegame()
{
    _previousScale = Time.timeScale;
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

public void unpausegame()
{
    Time.timeScale =  _previousScale;
}
```

Further note. I set `private float _previousScale = 1;` becuase I see an issue incase you call unpausegame before pausegame. If you did not assign it, it will default to 0 and you risk to set Time.timescale to 0 also in unpausegame.

Comment: Does it have to be initialized with 1 though?

Comment: I thought it would be safer. In case we unpause it before pausing. I see no harm in that and it could solve unseen issues. Let me add a note in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store your previous value in a variable (`YourVariable = Time.timeScale`) then when you resume set the timescale equals to your variable. (`Time.timeScale = YourVariable`)

I don't know if this is very optimized but it will work I think !